# How to send a confirmation email to sender and to me after form submission

Tags: php

I would like to send a confirmation email to the user who submitted the form and another email to me with the details which the user inputted, here is my form:

```
<form class="" action="." id="dateForm" method="POST">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dfName" placeholder="Name" required> 
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="dfEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="dfPhone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dfDate" placeholder="Schedule a call" required>
      <textarea id="dfMessage" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message"  required></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

And here is my php which works perfect for sending the emails to me.

```
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$date = trim($_POST['date']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);

function is_email_valid($email) {
return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

if( isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($phone) && isset($date) && isset($message) && is_email_valid($email) ) {

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "New inquiry request from Olho";

$body = <<<EOD
<strong>Name:</strong> $name <br>
<strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:$email?subject=feedback" "email me">$email</a> <br> <br>
<strong>Phone:</strong> $phone <br>
<strong>Booking Date:</strong> $date <br>
<strong>Message:</strong> $message <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

So what I would like is to receive another email after the one send to me which will contain a confirmation message like "Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you as soon as possible."

I've tried to use this but I am not receiving the confirmation email:

```
$conf_subject = 'Your recent enquiry';
$conf_sender = 'Olho';
$msg = $name . ",\n\nThank you for your recent enquiry. A member of our 
team will respond to your message as soon as possible.";

$headers2 = "From: $conf_sender <myemail@gmail.com>\r\n";
$headers2 .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers2 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail( $email, $conf_subject, $msg, $headers2 );
```

Comment: Maybe your mail gets marked as spam. If you entered `myemail@gmail.com` its the same as the `From`in your header, which is suspicious for most spam recognition :) - so have a look at your gmail spam folder

Comment: Checked it but unfortunately there is nothing in the spam as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for first mail to be completed and then should send second email as below code:

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    $conf_subject = 'Your recent enquiry';
    $conf_sender = 'Olho';
    $msg = $name . ",\n\nThank you for your recent enquiry. A member of our 
    team will respond to your message as soon as possible.";

    $headers2 = "From: $conf_sender <myemail@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $headers2 .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers2 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    mail( $email, $conf_subject, $msg, $headers2 );
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Tried the check with the if but still I do not receive the confirmation email I am still receiving only the email which is for me with the data inputted from the user :/

Comment: try to debug your code. Put ini_set("display_errors",1); on top of your php file which shows if there is any error. Try to print all variables before sending second email and check if all variables value are as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The issue was that actually everything was working BUT the second mail(.....) the first $var was not getting the $_POST['email'] so I replaced it to look like this: mail( $_POST['email'], $conf_subject, $msg, $headers2 ); and everything works like charm.

Comment: Cool, happy it helped you :)